# Get users who have permission through a sharing link Powershell sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, powershell-script, sharepoint-permissions

I want to generate a report of every document and permissions on it.
Permissions contains General Permission and Users who have permission through a sharing link/ or external sharing link.
When I run a code I get a result like  "SharingLinks.fdbe4441-98ec-47f5-9795-78f8e6e826e9.OrganizationEdit.00e9b96f-8eb7-4a68-b162-f7accc9fec66  : Contribute"
It means this document has been shared with Sharing Link having Contribute permission. 
Please see the Image below. It shows all the users having permission. But how can I get this info using Powershell script (PnP-Powershell) [image: user permissions]

Comment: Looking for a similar approach. All I can think so far is to grab all the items in a list and filter by the ones which has unique accessrules defined

Comment: Did you manage to get PowerShell for your requirement? I have the same requirement and coudnt find any script

Answer (score 0):

```
#$fileUrl -NewFolder/logo.png
$file = Get-PnPFile -Url $fileUrl -AsListItem

Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $file -Property RoleAssignments
$members = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $roleAssignments -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, Member
$member = $roleAssignments.Member 
#list of users 
$Users = Get-PnPProperty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ClientObject $member -Property Users 
#Return Accesstype
$accessType = $roleAssignments.RoleDefinitionBindings.Name;
   if ($member.Title -like "SharingLinks*") {
            if ($Users -ne $null) {
                $array = foreach ($user in $Users) {
                Write-host $user.LoginName, $accessType
                }
           }
    }
```