# Flow: get shared users from shared folder - sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, flow, external-users

We need to get a list of all external users (their e-mail) who have access to a specific shared folder.

We must archieve this with a **Power Automate Flow**.
I just tryed to do this, with "get file (only properties)" and then iterate over -> "shared with" values but i didn't get any other user, and really don't know why.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

How did you iterate over "shared with" value?

Per my research, We could create sharing link for a file or folder, however there is no such way to find existing sharing links using flow.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/manage-list-item-file-permissions

I suggest you consider using powershell or audit log:

[Get users who have permission through a sharing link Powershell sharepoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260574/get-users-who-have-permission-through-a-sharing-link-powershell-sharepoint-onlin)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-sharing-auditing?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: ok, I ll look into that Thanks!